# Windows PowerShell command not executed in a batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have the following commands written on a batch file to obtain my computer's public IP from a remote URL via powershell command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :MyIP2
timeout /t 50
EXIT /B 0
:MyIP2
echo Obtaining my IP...
For /f %%A in ('powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(Invoke-Webrequest http://componentsearch.everscrape.com/scraper/ip).content"') Do echo %%A
EXIT /B 0
```

Now when I try to execute the batch file (even run as administrator), I got the following ouptut instead of the public IP of the computer I'm using.

```
Obtaining my IP...
Invoke-Webrequest
Internet
At
+
+
+
+
d
```

I'm currently running Windows Home with all the updates installed. Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The powershell command by itself isn't working for me. Are you sure the Everscrape site is up? I do this to find the external IP address: `for /f "tokens=*" %%e in ('%__APPDIR__%curl.exe ipecho.net/plain 2^>nul') do set "extIP=%%e" & echo %extIP%`

Comment: Yes, the rest of the computers using the same script are working just fine and able to obtain the IP. I will try your code instead though

Comment: @Qwerty it seems your code doesn't work either on my computer. It returns "ECHO is off." Any idea about this now?

Comment: That depends on whether you have curl.exe installed. You can open a command prompt and type `where curl`. If it doesn't find it, the command won't work. If you do, you can try just `curl.exe ipecho.net/plain` to see if that works. Otherwise, npocmaka's solution below works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer to make sure there is clarity on this.

1. You specify in your question that all other devices work with your current script, besides this one device.
2. You posted an error after attempting the ode provided by Npocmaka which states:

```
 Invoke-Webrequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again. At line:1 char:2 + (Invoke-Webrequest "http://componentsearch.everscrape.com/scraper/ip" ... +
```

This error has a clear message, well two in fact. It shows you the dependancy on IE as a parser on windows and more importantly it shows you the fix in this line:

```
Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again
```

Simply adding the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter will therefore directly solve the issue without needing to run IE initially.

This is also clearly stipulated in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest?view=powershell-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
For /f  "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(Invoke-Webrequest """http://componentsearch.everscrape.com/scraper/ip""").content"') Do echo %%A
```

or

```
echo Obtaining my IP...
for /f  "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (
    'powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(Invoke-Webrequest """http://componentsearch.everscrape.com/scraper/ip""").content"'
) do (
    set "my_ip=%%A"
) 

echo %my_ip%
```

the URL needs to be in double quotes but in order to escape them when called from batch you need to use triple double quotes.

Comment: You can drop the triple double quotes actually by adding the url in single quotes. `...('powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(Invoke-Webrequest 'http://componentsearch.everscrape.com/scraper/ip').content"')...`

Comment: Hi, I tried your code from above and this is the result

`Obtaining my IP...
Invoke-Webrequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or
Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Invoke-Webrequest "http://componentsearch.everscrape.com/scraper/ip" ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: That error is VERY clear. You did state that your origininal code worked on other PC's so read the error carefully.

Comment: Yes this error did clear it up to me. Thanks

Comment: Good, I am glad to hear that `:)`! Did you solve it with `-UseBasicParsing`?

Comment: No, my original code works right after I launched the Internet Explorer for the first time. It was a fresh installed windows and there's a blind spot about how batch files are dependent with IE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue seem to occur on fresh installed windows. To fix, launch the Internet Explorer and select Recommended Settings.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! I am updating my script with `-UserBasicParsing` now. Thanks :)

Comment: it is `-UseBasicParsing` not `-UserBasicParsing` so make sure you add it correctly, else you'll have more failures.